# VueJS 2.x Table with Multiple ComboBox Filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using VueJS 2.x (JavaScript) with Vuex to get data in a table.
I also have two filters made with combobox.
By selecting filters, I need filter the list of previously get data. Filters can also be used together.
How can I recover the filters?

I use simple `<table>... <tbody><tr v-for="(item, index) in list>...</tr>"</table>` and for filter `<select><option></option></select>`

Tnx for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to filter your data is to use `computed` properties, because this is what they are meant to do.

so for your select options:

```html
<select v-model="filter">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

your table:

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in getFilteredItems> {{ item }} </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

you script:

```js
data: {
    items : [5,10,15,20,25],
    filter : 0
  },
  computed : {
      getFilteredItems() {
          return this.items.filter(item => // apply the filter according to this.filter);
      }
  }
```

Your computed will be called each time `this.filter` will change, or when `this.items` will change.
You can read more about computed properties in [vue docs computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Of course you need to apply your own code here, this is just an example.

Answer (score -1):

First of all bind your selects to some variables using v-model and listen for change event. For Example :

```
<select v-model="filter" @change="applyFilter">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

You gonna need another list to store filtered items and a method to apply filter.

```
  data: {
    items : [5,10,15,20,25],
    filteredItems : [],
    filter : 0
  },
  methods : {
      applyFilter (){
          this.filteredItems = this.items.filter(item => item > this.test);
      }
  }
```

This is a very basic implementation with a single filter. But you can add as many as you want. Edit the filter method with given filters. Add same change event to all select elements. (Since you said that you need multiple filters)

Comment: when presenting the data in different way - like filtered data, it is best to use computed properties because they will update automatically when `this.filter` changes anywhere (not just on change of select) and this is what they are designed for.